Copy the code text from MS Visual Studio 2022 and keeping the source color
From time to time I like to copy bits of code out of Visual Studio to send to co-workers. In previous versions of Visual Studio the copy/paste would include the color coding. In VS 2022 it's all black. To paraphrase Henry Ford... "The code you copy can be any color you want, as long as that color is black." The rich text option in VS 2019 (that is discussed in other StackOverflow posts) doesn't fix the color problem--at least for me--in VS2022. My current work around is to copy/paste code into VS 2017 then re-copy paste it from there, but that's a bit of a nuisance. Does anyone know of a better solution for VS 2022?

After my testing, it is indeed such an issue.
I also found a post similar to yours, you can refer to this link:
Copy text with color highlighting from Visual Studio
As mentioned in the link above, I recommend that you report this issue to DC:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
In addition, when a problem is raised by many users, it will often be solved quickly.
